# Problems parsing XML/XLIFF with inline elements

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xliff

I am trying to parse xliff (XML) variant from SDL Trados translation software, which contains translations, and the "sdlxliff" file I'm parsing looks like this (somewhat simplified and "prettified").

XML/XLIFF file being processed ("sample.sdlxliff"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xliff xmlns:sdl="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2" sdl:version="1.0"><file original="\\TRADOS_SERVER\Trados\2017\Doc_Helps\en-US\import\Test.xml" datatype="x-sdlfilterframework2" source-language="en-US" target-language="hr-HR"><header><sniff-info><detected-encoding detection-level="Certain" encoding="utf-8"/><detected-source-lang detection-level="Guess" lang="en-US"/><props><value key="xmlDeclaration">true</value><value key="standalone">yes</value><value key="HasUtf8Bom">false</value><value key="IsFragment">false</value></props></sniff-info></header>
<body>
  <trans-unit id="a1f4768e-a026-46c2-b65d-599d2108d176">
    <source>
      <g id="461">Add or edit text: </g>Just begin typing. The blinking insertion point indicates where your text starts. To edit text,   <g id="462">select the text</g>, then type. Use the controls in the Format <g id="463">  <g id="464"/></g> sidebar on the right.
    </source>
    <seg-source>
      <g id="461">
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="182">Add or edit text:</mrk> </g>
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="183">Just begin typing.</mrk> 
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="184">The blinking insertion point indicates where your text starts.</mrk> 
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="185">To edit text, <g id="462">select the text</g>, then type.</mrk> 
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="186">Use the controls in the Format <g id="463"><g id="464"/></g> sidebar on the right.</mrk>
    </seg-source>
    <target>
      <g id="461">
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="182">Dodajte ili uredite tekst:</mrk> </g>
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="183">Samo počnite tipkati.</mrk> 
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="184">Trepereća točka umetanja pokazuje gdje počinje vaš tekst.</mrk> 
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="185">Za uređivanje teksta <g id="462">odaberite tekst</g>, zatim unesite tekst.</mrk> 
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="186">Upotrijebite kontrole u rubnom stupcu Formatiraj <g id="463"><g id="464"/></g> s desne strane.</mrk>
    </target> 
    <blahblahblah></blahblahblah>
  </trans-unit>
  <trans-unit id="7f7ede5e-75b9-403a-b1c6-43f654ea8245">
    <source>
      <g id="492"><g id="493">The toolbar with buttons.</g></g>
    </source>
    <seg-source>
      <g id="492">
      <g id="493"> 
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="199">The toolbar with buttons.</mrk></g></g>
    </seg-source>
    <target>
      <g id="492">
      <g id="493"> 
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="199">Alatna traka sa tipkama.</mrk></g></g>
    </target>
    <blahblahblah></blahblahblah>
  </trans-unit>
</body>
</file></xliff>
```

So, the XML/XLIFF file has "seg-source" and "target" parts, which I am interested in, and which I want to extract and later print to plain tab-delimited TXT file, or whatever..

However, I am having problems with inline tags - like in this line:

```
<mrk mtype="seg" mid="185">To edit text, <g id="462">select the text</g>, then type.</mrk>
```

-> where I am getting only the part of the string before the first inline `'<g id="xxx">'` tag :(

Instead of "**To edit text, select the text, then type.**", I am getting only "**To edit text,**".

Python code I have tried:

```
# parsesdlxliff-test.py:

from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("sample.sdlxliff")
root = tree.getroot()

for element in root:
  pass # not important
  # now the children
  for all_tags in element.findall('.//'):
    if 'mrk' in all_tags.tag:
      attrs = all_tags.attrib
      numb = attrs.get("mid")
      # remove all internal tags within 'mrk', leave only clean string/text? - how?
      print(numb, all_tags.text)
```

The result I'm getting with this code:

```
182 Add or edit text:
183 Just begin typing.
184 The blinking insertion point indicates where your text starts.
185 To edit text, 
186 Use the controls in the Format 
182 Dodajte ili uredite tekst:
183 Samo počnite tipkati.
184 Trepereća točka umetanja pokazuje gdje počinje vaš tekst.
185 Za uređivanje teksta 
186 Upotrijebite kontrole u rubnom stupcu Formatiraj 
199 The toolbar with buttons.
199 Alatna traka sa tipkama.
```

As can be seen in resulting lines no. 185 and 186 ('mid' numbers), there is text missing after the first inline tag (both in 'seg-source' and in 'target').

Ultimately, what I want to get is something like this (illustration only):

```
Add or edit text: <TAB> Dodajte ili uredite tekst:
To edit text, select the text, then type. <TAB> Za uređivanje teksta odaberite tekst, zatim unesite tekst.
Use the controls in the Format sidebar on the right. <TAB> Upotrijebite kontrole u rubnom stupcu Formatiraj s desne strane.
```

I.e. tab-delimited source-target **sentence** pairs.

I can pair them later using 'mid' numbers, but only after I manage to get the whole strings (get rid of internal tags somehow?)...

In short, how do I get/extract the whole strings, including the parts after any `'<gxxx>'` or `'</g>'` internal tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like this should work:

```
import lxml.html as lh #while an xml parser would be more appropriate, in this case it's cleaner to use an html parser

diff = """[your xml above]"""
doc = lh.fromstring(diff.encode('utf-8'))
engs = []
cros = []
eng = doc.xpath('//seg-source//mrk')
cro = doc.xpath('//target//mrk')
for e in eng:
    engs.append(e.text_content())
for c in cro:
    cros.append(c.text_content())
for eng, cro in zip(engs, cros):
    print(eng, '<tab>',cro)
```

Output:

```
Add or edit text: <tab> Dodajte ili uredite tekst:
Just begin typing. <tab> Samo počnite tipkati.
The blinking insertion point indicates where your text starts. <tab> Trepereća točka umetanja pokazuje gdje počinje vaš tekst.
To edit text, select the text, then type. <tab> Za uređivanje teksta odaberite tekst, zatim unesite tekst.
Use the controls in the Format  sidebar on the right. <tab> Upotrijebite kontrole u rubnom stupcu Formatiraj  s desne strane.
The toolbar with buttons. <tab> Alatna traka sa tipkama.
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work...
But, I'm not sure how to pass the filename as argument to the script?

Comment: Solved, with some additions:


`import lxml.html as lh 


with open('sample.sdlxliff', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:

    x = f.readlines()


diff = str(x)

doc = lh.fromstring(diff)

engs = []

cros = []

eng = doc.xpath('//seg-source//mrk')

cro = doc.xpath('//target//mrk')

for e in eng:

  engs.append(e.text_content())

for c in cro:

  cros.append(c.text_content())

for eng, cro in zip(engs, cros):

  eng = eng.replace("  ", " ")

  cro = cro.replace("  ", " ")

  print(eng, '\t',cro)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Using the html parser seems to do the trick for me.

Could you explain why it is better to use the html parser? I thought sdlxliff is a valid XML-Document.